# Access DB while updating

Tags: database, sqlite, flask, scheduler

I'm managing a server using Flask for my little project.

The server has a local Database file.
I've updated my Database every day and it takes about 10 minutes.

While managing the server, I have a question.
During 10 minutes to update the DB, if I access the DB what happens to the DB?

Can access? or exception happen?

I'm using sqlite3 and Flask scheduler for updating DB every day.

Comment: Only one connection can write to a sqlite database at a time. Normally, when it's doing so, no other connection can read. If you want them to be able to, look into WAL journal mode.

Comment: And if I try to connect,  It's raised an exception?